# Interbase 2009 + php

Tags: php, interbase

Есть база intrerbase ods 13.1, есть ли возможность подключиться к ней с php? Ранее с такой базой не работал, пару дней погуглив пришел к выводу, что с версией ib 7.
5 проблем бы не было. Но факт у меня она выше.

Comment: https://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_FIREBIRD